# Remove excess white space from string

Tags: vb.net, spaces

I want to remove the excess white spaces using VB.net

ex.

```
"The   Quick          Brown Fox"
```

I want output

```
"The Quick Brown Fox"
```

Thanks,
inchika

Answer (score 25):

You can use a simple regular expression for that:

```
Dim cleaned As String = Regex.Replace(input, "\s{2,}", " ")
```

Answer (score 8):

I realize that this question is fairly old, but there is another option that doesn't involve Regex, or manually looping through the string and replacing:

```vb
Private Function StripSpaces(input As String) As String
    Return String.Join(" ", input.Split(New Char() {}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
End Function
```

And the C# equivalent:

```cs
private string StripSpaces(string input)
{
    return string.Join(" ", input.Split((char[])null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
}
```

Using a "null" value as the split character on [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) causes the split character to be all characters that return true if they were sent to [`Char.IsWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Therefore, calling the method this way will split your string on all whitespace, remove the empty strings, then re-join it together with a single space in between each split array element.

Answer (score 5):

What you actually want is to compact any multiple white space to a single space, and one way to do that is to search for two spaces and replace them with a single space, until there are no two adjascent spaces left, something like this:

```
   Dim myString As String = "The   Quick     Brown     Fox"
   While myString.IndexOf("  ") <> -1
       myString = myString.Replace("  ", " ")
   End While
   Console.WriteLine(myString)
```

However, this is not fool-proof because of some ideosyncracies of [.net strings](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx), this might go into an endless loop, but only for some very odd inputs.

---

EDIT: This particular processing is faster (and simpler) using a regular expression, as pointed in the othe answers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I just used REGEX

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Dim output As String = Regex.Replace("The   Quick          Brown Fox","\\s+" , " ")
```

Comment: This does not work if the string is more than one line.